# Cannot implicitly convert type to generic type when generic type is parent of type

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, generics, delegates

I tried buiding a game made with Unity by building objects I called WorldObjects. WorldObjects are spawned via a data class (WorldObjectData) that is governed by a manager (WorldObjectDataManager). The part that needs fixing is the process that spawns WorldObjects. Long story short, I have to pass two generic parameters to a WorldObject builder: the first one is the type of the WorldObject, the second one is the **type** of data class (so that the script can fetch the correct WorldObjectDataManager).

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'Sandbox.GUI.Sandbox.BuildButton.BuildMenuEntry<Sandbox.Selectables.Entities.JobInteractables.WorldObjects.Consoles.Console,
> Sandbox.Selectables.Entities.JobInteractables.WorldObjects.Consoles.ConsoleData>'
> to 'Sandbox.GUI.Sandbox.BuildButton.BuildMenuEntry<T,
> G>'   Assembly-CSharp C:\Unity Projects\80s
> Sandbox\Assets\Scripts\GUI\Sandbox\BuildButtons\BuildButtonsChildren\BuildControl.cs  16  Active

This is the error I get when I try to compile line Console.GetEntry():

```
using Sandbox.Selectables.Entities.JobInteractables.WorldObjects;
using Sandbox.Selectables.Entities.JobInteractables.WorldObjects.Consoles;

namespace Sandbox.GUI.Sandbox.BuildButton // Used to spawn WorldObjects via a button
{
    /// <summary>
    /// BuildButton used for control buildings (e.g.: consoles)
    /// </summary>
    public class BuildControl<T, G> : CreateBuildButtonNew<T, G> where T : WorldObject where G : WorldObjectData
    {
        protected override BuildMenuEntry<T, G>[] GetBuildMenuEntries()
        {
            return new BuildMenuEntry<T, G>[]
            {
                Console.GetEntry()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Console.GetEntry is coded as follows:

```
public static BuildMenuEntry<Console, ConsoleData> GetEntry()
        {
            return new BuildMenuEntry<Console, ConsoleData> // Console and ConsoleData inherit from WorldObject and WorldObjectData respectively
            {
                entryName = UIStringID, // string
                entrysMaterials = new WorldObjectMaterial[] { WorldObjectMaterial.Steel }, // WorldObjectMaterial is an enum
                associatedFunction = InitializeByStatic<Console, ConsoleData> // the spawning function
            };
        }
```

Finally, BuildMenuEntry:

```
using Sandbox.Selectables.Entities.JobInteractables.WorldObjects;

namespace Sandbox.GUI.Sandbox.BuildButton
{
    public struct BuildMenuEntry<T, G> where T : WorldObject where G : WorldObjectData
    {
        public string entryName;
        public WorldObjectMaterial[] entrysMaterials;
        public SpawnWorldObject<T, G> associatedFunction;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what's the problem here since T and G are constrained to be respectively WorldObject and WorldObjectData, and Console.GetEntry returns a class whose generic types inherit from WorldObject and WorldObjectData.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe it's because `GetEntry` requires a more derived type than `BuildControl` requires. If you constrain `BuildControl` to `Console` and `ConsoleData`, does the error go away?

Comment: _"Cannot implicitly convert type to generic type when generic type is parent of type"_ -- your premise is flawed. You believe that the generic types involved have a parent (base)/child (derived) relationship when in fact they do not. Only the _type parameters_ do. But having type parameters that are base & child do not make the generic types themselves base & child. See duplicate.

Comment: @RufusL Yes, once I constrain BuildControl to Console and ConsoleData the error goes away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to put a `BuildMenuEntry<Console, ConsoleData>` inside an array of `BuildMenuEntry<T, G>`.

---

Here's a situation that will help understand the issue.

Your class `BuildControl<T, G>` is generic. Let's imagine we use it as a `BuildControl<Car, CarData>`. In this case, your method can be read like this:

```cs
protected override BuildMenuEntry<Car, CarData>[] GetBuildMenuEntries()
{
    return new BuildMenuEntry<Car, CarData>[]
    {
        Console.GetEntry()
    };
}
```

Now we can see that `Consol.GetEntry` returns a `BuildMenuEntry<Console, ConsoleData>`. You can't put a `BuildMenuEntry<Console, ConsoleData>` inside an array of `BuildMenuEntry<Car, CarData>` because `Console` isn't `Car` and `ConsoleData` isn't `CarData`.

What you put in the array of `BuildMenuEntry<T, G>` must be `BuildMenuEntry<T, G>` items, where `T` and `G` are still generics, not something concrete.